# Computing the total Pontrjagin class of quaternionic projective space

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

This is Problem 20-A in Milnor-Stasheff's book Characteristic Classes:

Let $\tau$ be the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^m(H)$, where $H$ is the quaternion algebra. $\gamma$ is the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{P}^m(H)$. Use the isomorphism $$\tau\oplus\text{Hom}_H(\gamma,\gamma)\cong\text{Hom}_H(\gamma,H^{m+1})$$
to show that $$p(\tau)=\frac{(1+u)^{2m+2}}{1+4u}$$
$u=c_2(\gamma)$ is a generator of $H^4(\mathbb{P}^m(H))$.

I'm not sure what's wrong with my proof: Take Pontrjagin classes on both sides of the isomorphism. Since $p(\text{Hom}_H(\gamma,H))=(1+u)^2$, we have $p(\text{Hom}_H(\gamma,H^{m+1}))=(1+u)^{2m+2}$. Because $\text{Hom}_H(\gamma,\gamma)\cong\epsilon^4$ is trivial bundle, $p(\tau\oplus\text{Hom}_H(\gamma,\gamma))=p(\tau)$. Therefore, $p(\tau)=(1+u)^{2m+2}$.

Where does $1+4u$ come from ? I appreciate any hints or answers.

Comment: Why is $\text{Hom}(\gamma,\gamma)$ a trivial bundle?

Comment: I think that's because $\gamma$ is a quaternionic line bundle and any quaternionic linear map from a quaternionic line to itself is left multiplication by an element in $H$.

Comment: But to do the characteristic class computation, you have to work over $\Bbb C$, no? Note that you yourself wrote $\epsilon^4$, not $\epsilon^1$.

Comment: Yes. My idea is that $\text{Hom}(\gamma,\gamma)$ is trivial quaternionic line bundle, which is isomorphic to trivial rank 4 real bundle $\epsilon^4$. Since trivial bundle has total Pontrjagin class $1$, the total Pontrjagin class is equal to that of tangent bundle.

Comment: No, definitely not a rank 4 real bundle. It is a.rank 4 complex bundle. I suggest you compute $p_1(V^*\otimes V)$ for a complex rank 2 bundle $V$.

Comment: I'm still confused. It is Hom over $H$ not Hom over $\mathbb{C}$. Shouldn't this imply that $\text{Hom}_H(\gamma,\gamma)\cong H$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the misconception present in the question is that for a quaternionic vector space $V$, the endomorphism space $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{H}}(V, V)$ is a quaternionic vector space, just as $\mathrm{Hom}_{K}(V, V)$ would be a $K$-vector space for any vector space $V$ over a field $K$. If this was true, then it would indeed be canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$, as it has a canonical element, the identity endomorphism.

However, this is not true, due to non-commutativity of the quaternions. Think about how you would define this vector space structure, and you will notice that you only get a vector space structure over the *center* of $\mathbb{H}$, which is $\mathbb{R}$.

The upshot is that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{H}}(\gamma, \gamma)$ is not a rank $1$ quaternionic vector bundle, but a rank $4$ real vector bundle (which actually has a canonical section, given by the identity elements, but this does not really matter).

Let us calculate its first Pontrjagin class.

(1) Recall that $\gamma$ itself is a rank $4$ real vector bundle with three almost complex structures $I$, $J$ and $K$ satisfying the quaternion relations. In particular, it has an associated rank $2$ complex vector bundle $\gamma_{\mathbb{C}}$ using the complex structure $I$.

(2) There is a canonical isomorphism
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{H}}(\gamma, \gamma) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(\gamma_{\mathbb{C}}, \gamma_{\mathbb{C}})$$
given by sending $A \otimes (a + bi) \mapsto a\cdot A + b\cdot AI$. To see that this map is an isomorphism, we show that it is injective (from which the claim follows from dimension reasons): The general element of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{H}}(\gamma, \gamma) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ has the form $A \otimes 1 + B \otimes i$. Hence if this gets sent to zero under our map, then we would have $A = - BI$. But $A$ commutes with the left $\mathbb{H}$-action, while $BI$ does not, unless $B=0$. But if $B=0$, then also $A=0$.

(3) We can now calculate
$$p_1\big(\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{H}}(\gamma, \gamma)\big) 
= -c_2\big(\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{H}}(\gamma, \gamma) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}\big) = -c_2\big(\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(\gamma_{\mathbb{C}}, \gamma_{\mathbb{C}})\big) = -c_2(\gamma_{\mathbb{C}} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \gamma_{\mathbb{C}}^*).$$

(4) To get a formula for the Chern class of the tensor product, we can use the Chern character. The first terms of the Chern character are
$$\mathrm{ch}(E) = \mathrm{rk}(E) + c_1(E) + \frac{1}{2}\big(c_1(E)^2 - c_2(E)\big) + \dots.$$
If now $E$ and $F$ are two vector bundles of rank two with $c_1(E) = c_1(F) = 0$, then the formula $\mathrm{ch}(E \otimes F) = \mathrm{ch}(E)\mathrm{ch}(F)$ yields
$$ 4 - \frac{1}{2} c_2(E \oplus F) + \dots = \left(2 - \frac{1}{2} c_2(E) + \dots\right)\left(2 - \frac{1}{2} c_2(F) + \dots\right) = 4 - c_2(E) - c_2(F) + \dots$$
Hence $c_2(E \oplus F) = 2c_2(E) + 2c_2(F)$.

(5) Finishing off the calculation, we get
$$ p_1\big(\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{H}}(\gamma, \gamma)\big) = -c_2(\gamma_{\mathbb{C}} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \gamma_{\mathbb{C}}^*) = - 2c_2(\gamma_{\mathbb{C}}) - 2c_2(\gamma_{\mathbb{C}}^*) = -4 c_2(\gamma_{\mathbb{C}}) = - 4u,$$
hence
$$p\big(\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{H}}(\gamma, \gamma)\big) = 1 - 4u.$$
What's bugging me, though, is the sign difference. Are there different conventions at play here?

**Edit:**

I get $$p\big(\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{H}}(\gamma, \mathbb{H}) \big) = (1-u)^2,$$
so it seems to me that the generator that Milnor-Stasheff refer to is $u = - c_2(\gamma)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured out where I did wrong. I thought the right multiplications by $i,j,k$ would give three sections of that hom bundle but actually they don’t because we define the projective space by quotienting out left multiplication.